# ROSTopics: Only advertiser can publish?

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a simple question about the ROS communication between nodes.

Only the  node that advertises a topic can publish to it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63521/rostopics:-only-advertiser-can-publish?/) by [Median](https://answers.ros.org/users/4366/median/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes and no :-)

A node needs to create a publisher, which advertises a topic, in order to send anything. So "yes": a node can't send anything on a topic if it doesn't advertise it.

However, multiple nodes can advertise the same topic and publish on it (as well as multiple subscribers can listen). So "no": not only the first node that advertises a topic is allowed to publish on a given topic name.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Median](https://answers.ros.org/users/4366/median/) on 2013-05-26**:
What that means is that multiple nodes may advertise the same ROS topic, is that right?

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-05-26**:
Correct! Updated my answer to explicitly state that.